# Using indexOf to remove an Object from a list?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, indexof

So, I have seen this piece of code:

```
removeOrder = (order) ->
    index = listOfOrders.indexOf(order)
    if index isnt -1
        listOfOrders.splice index, 1
```

where `order` is an object like this:

```
order = {
    id: whatever
    field1: whatever
    ...
}
```

This is working now because the `order` that is passed as argument is referencing some object in `listOfOrders`, something like `removeOrder(listOfOrders[i])`. But my question is, is this safe? I mean, I think it would be better to iterate over the list of orders and search for an object with the same id, for example, and remove it.

As far as I know `indexOf` is Ok when the object we are searching for is a "simple" object (a number, a string, etc.).

Comment: You are right, but I've omitted that part intentionally. I'm just asking about the use of the strict equality.

Comment: This code should work while `order` references to some element of `listOfOrders` array

Comment: @t.niese Fair enough. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [These docs for indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), indexOf uses strict equality `===`.

```
var a = {id:1};
var b = {id:1};

a === a; // this is true
a === b; // this is false
```

So its safe to in general for objects

You do need to check that indexOf != -1 before the splice though

Comment: Yes, "in my case", but I'm not pretty sure it is a good practice :p

Comment: Why are you "not pretty sure"?

Comment: Because we are relying on `===`. What happens if instead of calling `removeOrder(listOfOrders[i])` we call it like `removeOrder(anotherOrder)` ? Then the indexOf will always return -1

Comment: @enrmarc it depends what you are about to achieve. Is it important that `removeOrder` will only remove an exact object, or are `removeOrderA`  and `removeOrderB` equal if there `id` is the same, even if they are different objects? If there are two different Object with the same `id` that should be identical then you might have an design issue (but not necessarily).

Answer (score 0):

The function works as inteded assuming that there is exactly one reference to the object in the array.

If the object isn't in the array (or you are calling it with a clone of an object in the array), the index will be -1 and the `splice` call will remove the last item in the array instead. As this is not a reasonable behaviour, there should really be a check for that (which I see that you added).

The `indexOf` method works reliably for object references, but it natually has to be looking for the same object.

Looking for an object with a specific propery value would also work, but it goes with the same assumptions; the value has to occur exactly once in the array to work as intended.

Comment: Yes, I had omitted the checking. The question has been edited. The question is more about the strict equality `===`

Answer (score 0):

```
var removeOrder = function(order)
{
  var index = listOfOrders.indexOf(order);
  if (index != -1)
    return listOfOrders.splice(index, 1); //for chaining?
  return listOfOrders;
}
```

It's safe to use `indexOf` if the intended purpose is to remove an object from the array by it's reference.

If you want to remove first object by `id` let's say, you would use something like:

```
var removeOrderById = function(orderId)
{
  var orders = listOfOrders.filter(function(item) 
  {
    return item.id == orderId;
  });
  if (orders.length > 0)
  {
    var index = listOfOrders.indexOf(orders[0]);
    return listOfOrders.splice(index, 1); //for chaining?
  }
  return listOfOrders;
}
```

Conclusion: it's all about the use case.